# Unable to get jwt from backend server

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

What my app should do is it uses google oauth for login and the server will then return a create a user (if user has not been created) and log the user in (by creating session).

I am certain my backend works because i have tested everything with postman.
However, i am unable to handle the creation of user (if user has not been created) and console.log my jwt to assure myself that it is working. I am strongly convinced it has to do with my react native code below.

Furthermore, the log which says "this is not working" is not being printed in google chrome as well.

-

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Platform, Image, Text, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { GoogleSignin, statusCodes, GoogleSigninButton } from 'react-native-google-signin';
import NavigationManager from './containers/TabNavigator';
import PhoneStorageManager from './assets/jwtStorageManager';

GoogleSignin.configure({
  forceConsentPrompt: true,
  webClientId: '<client-id>
});

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {failed: "NOOO", user: null, jwt: null};
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
  }

  signIn = async () => {
    try {
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      this.setState({ failed: "SUCCESS" });
      this.setState({ user: userInfo });

  const resp = await fetch('<url>', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      session: {
        token: userInfo.idToken,
        authprovider: "google"
      }
    })
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  this.setState({ jwt: resp.jwt }, ()=> {
    console.log(this.state.jwt, 'jwt');
    PhoneStorageManager._storeData("key",this.state.jwt); 
    //so that i can use jwt for further api calls
  });
  console.log("this is not working");
} catch (error) {
  if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
    // user cancelled the login flow
    this.setState({ failed: "CANCELLED" });
  } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
    // operation (f.e. sign in) is in progress already
    this.setState({ failed: "PROGRESS" });
  } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
    // play services not available or outdated
    this.setState({ failed: "NO AVAIL" });
  } else {
    // some other error happened
    this.setState({error: error});
    this.setState({ failed: "some other error happened" });
  }
}


}

  render() {
    if (this.state.jwt) {
      console.log(this.state.jwt);
      return (
        <NavigationManager JWT={this.state.jwt}/>
      );
    }
    else 
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
              <Image source={require('./assets/auditlogo.png')} style={[styles.logo]} />
              <GoogleSigninButton
              style={{ width: 192, height: 48 }}
              size={GoogleSigninButton.Size.Wide}
              color={GoogleSigninButton.Color.Dark}
              onPress={this.signIn}
              disabled={this.state.isSigninInProgress} />
              <Text style= {styles.instructions}>
                Please Sign in to continue.
              </Text>
        </View>
      );
  }
}
```

1) User presses google sign in button
2) Fetch api to create user if new user.
3) Fetch api to create session. (this returns jwt for further api calls)
4) Further api calls which uses jwt. (How do i get the jwt to be passed down?)

Comment: try console.log(error) inside catch block to see what goes wrong